# Will and would in the same sentence

Tags: will-would

I have read this [article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/news/national/kerala/muslim-quota-to-go-down-to-5867/article34676809.ece/amp/) in a Indian newspaper "The Hindu"

> The minority scholarship quota for Muslims **will** be reduced drastically from 80%  to 58.67% whereas the share of the entire christian community **would** be nearly 40.6% with the kerala (a state in India) High court ordering a population based allocation of the merit scholarship for the minorities.

My question here is , why **will** is used  at first place and **would** is used at the second place? can't we use **will** in both the places?

Comment: More context is needed. For example, the language makes sense if the quota reduction is predicted in all cases, whereas the Christian share prediction is predicated on the court outcome (and is therefore hypothetical). Please quote the preceding sentences that provide the context for the quota prediction.

Comment: @Chemomechanics  Thankyou so much for your help. Now I have edited and  provided the link for that news article.

Comment: Christian takes a capital C.

Comment: Note that Kerala and Christian are proper nouns, and these should be capitalised.

Comment: "will be reduced drastically" means it's a certainty. It is definitely going to be reduced drastically, whereas "would be nearly" implies some uncertainty, an estimate. Although you could use "will be nearly", I think "would" is better here if the intention is to express uncertainty.

Comment: I'd guess "would" is because it's an estimate based on adding up figures or performing other calculations. Sadly the article is paywalled but maybe someone could check what is being proposed.

Answer (score -1):

(The quoted section begins the article, so there is no additional context available.) I agree with you; either "will" or "would" should be used consistently here, as the Muslim/Christian quotas are being presented in parallel. "Will" presupposes that the court's ruling will certainly be applied; "would" is more tentative.